# How to add elements of list with particular indexes to a string?

Tags: python-2.7

If I have a list of words like this: `['one', 'two', 'three']`
and need to add only say 'two' and 'three' to a string with comma between them so the string would look like this: `two, three.` How to do it?
I know about += operator but maybe there are some other ways with *str.join* method or similar. So how to add elements of list with particular indexes to a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
s = ['one', 'two', 'three']

string = s[1]+","+s[2]
print string
```

output

two,three